# 3D Masyu - A Die

Tags: grid-deduction, three-dimensional, masyu

[image: 3D Masyu]

> **Fold this net into a cube and solve this 3D Masyu.**
> The original [Masyu rules](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu/) apply. In addition, question mark '?' should be replaced by either a black or white circle.

*Side note: Yeah, it's almost a die... I'm adding '?' to make sure that the solution is unique. ><*

**Addendum: Move '?' from the center of side $4$ to the center of side $2$.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By adding a

> white circle

we get

> [image: solution]

Answer (score 11):

## Solution

> [image: final]

## Explanation

When you fold this cube net, you would get this connection:

> [image: 001]

Start from the obvious one, the two adjacent black cells:

> [image: 002]

Then some more:

> [image: 003]
>  [image: 004]
>  There is a wall in the center since it will form a loop without the lines outside, so the yellow line extends to bottom.
>  [image: 005]

Consider this:
What if you connect the lines below the white cells, in the 6-celled side? (shown in dark green)

> [image: 006]

So the left one needs to be connected on the black cell.

> [image: 007]

Now for the question mark:

> If it is a black cell, then:
>  [image: 008]
>  So it will be a white cell.

Now, what if you put a horizontal line at the top left white cell, in the side with question mark?

> [image: 009]

So:

> [image: 010]

...and lastly:

> [image: 011]

Comment: (+1): congratulations, you past 3k rep! :)

Comment: @MrPie Thank you! (although I'm inactive sometimes)